# Web Worker Concurrency Exception

Tags: javascript, concurrency, web-worker

I have started to use web workers in some of my applications, and as you all know, 99% of the time you try to use something new, you use it wrong. So naturally I looked up its [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers) and I came across an interesting passage regarding thread safety:

> The Worker interface spawns real OS-level threads, and concurrency can
>   cause interesting effects in your code if you aren't careful. However,
>   in the case of web workers, the carefully controlled communication
>   points with other threads means that it's actually very hard to cause
>   concurrency problems.  There's no access to non-thread safe components
>   or the DOM and you have to pass specific data in and out of a thread
>   through serialized objects.  So you have to work really hard to cause
>   problems in your code

Has anyone been able to cause concurrency problems using web workers? So far my attempts at breaking the web worker implementation in Firefox and Chrome has failed.

Answer (score 0):

> So you have to work really hard to cause problems in your code

I think the problems this refers to aren't the problems that can come with concurrency in other multi-threaded environments, often stemming from the possibility of non-atomic operations, and so needing to use some technique to control access to a block of code to make sure memory doesn't get into a corrupted state. Because of the lack of blocking "wait until I receive something" calls in the API, I also suspect it can't mean problems that those sorts of calls can introduce, i.e. the forms of deadlock where each thread synchronously blocks until it receives a call from the other.

However, you could still get into a "logical" deadlock situation. Although you can't really "block" each worker, you could code up something where each worker (/main UI thread) won't ever move onto its useful work (whatever that is). E.g. if each worker followed an algorithm like:

1. Receives message from other
2. Sends message to other
3. Useful work

Then they wouldn't ever get to step 2, let alone step 3, because each would be waiting to receive messages before sending them. In Javascript the code would look a bit like:

```
self.onmessage = function(e) {
  self.postMessage(...);
  usefulWork();
};
```

I suspect the doc writers meant that to write an algorithm this way, and not write it in a way that means you won't deadlock, you have to "work really hard".

Admittedly, if this is what the documentation means, it's not very clear!